# How do I get a list of hidden applications a user has access to?

Tags: okta, okta-api

In the Okta UI there's an option to hide applications from the dashboard, which is exactly what we want.  There are some applications we want hidden in the Okta dashboard, but available in our custom applications.

But when we hide them from the dashboard, they also disappear from the list of a user's application links when pulling the user info from the API.

Any help on how to accomplish our task?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug. I would open up a ticket with [Okta Support](https://support.okta.com). A colleague of mine verified the same behavior.

As per http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/users.html#get-assigned-app-links you should get a JSON object with hidden set to false.

Comment: Thanks!  I thought I was going crazy haha.  Just filed a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a bug. As of next week in PREVIEW, a GET call will return all apps regardless of whether they're hidden in the UI. Within the JSON body, two property attributes determine whether the apps are hidden in the web and/or in Okta mobile.

```
{
    "visibility": {
        "autoSubmitToolbar": false,
        "hide": {
            "iOS": false,
            "web": false
        },
        "appLinks": {
            "mc": true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!   

I'm not sure what PREVIEW is though, is that a beta version of the API?  First Ive heard of it.  Any information on how to access it?

Comment: PREVIEW is just Okta's Developer Edition landscape. It is identical to the OKTA (or production) landscape except the code page is one to two weeks ahead of it. You may sign up for a free developer account on the PREVIEW landscape here: https://www.okta.com/developer/signup/